# why to use queue.Peek() instead of queue.First()/Last()

Tags: c#

Queue contains special method `queue.Peek()`, why should I use it when I can use general `queue.First()` and `queue.Last()` ?

Comment: Which queue class are you looking at?

Comment: There are multiple queue classes available in C#. For instance, [System.Collections.Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx), [System.Collections.Generic.Queue(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), or you may have been using a shorthand for [System.Messaging.MessageQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=VS.100).aspx), just as 3 examples.

Comment: I meant `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`

Comment: But do you see now why I asked the original question, and why your answer of "C# `Queue`" was insufficient?

Comment: well diffientely I didn't meant `MessageQueue` (because I wrote `Queue`) however now I know that c# contains two different queue: from System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic. However I think that these queries are likely very similar so my question is applicable for both of these queries so it doesn't matter which exactly queue I refer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Peek` is a classic method of a queue, where as `First` and `Last` are Linq methods. Since the queue most likely implements `IEnumerable` you get the methods First and Last which have no relevance to an strict queue.

---

EDIT

It's not the end of the world to bend the law of a queue. Sounds like you are using the structure to fit your needs. It might be confusing to the next programmer though who expects a queue to act like a queue. Maybe you create a class that extends Queue, called a StackedQueue. Then if someone needs to maintain your code they won't expect a queue's behavior

Comment: I see, but can I use these methods? since queue is `IEnumerable` they are garanteed to work, right? Why do I need extra `Peek` method then?. The issue is - I need to take element from another side of the `queue` and want to use `IEnumerable` methods for that

Comment: If you need to access the back of the queue, don't use a Queue.

Comment: @Rawling what to use then? (also I can use `queue` but cache the last added value)

Comment: The methods will work perfectly, however, semantically you don't need a queue. Perhaps a List or Array or Collection might fit you needs.

Comment: @MikeStewart but I need to `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` and enumerate and access first/last elements. I need a structure to hold bars for "moving average" indicator

Comment: You should take a look at LinkedList<T>