# is it possible to add .net source files to VS for studying / debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

without sources of general classes many questions arise (like one I've just asked [why to use queue.Peek() instead of queue.First()/Last()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506398/why-to-use-queue-peek-instead-of-queue-first-last/8506434#8506434))

Is it possible to add .net source files to VS? Like in Eclipse/Java?

Comment: Please elaborate on what your wanting to do.  What do you mean by .net source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About .NET Framework source code availability check this one:

[.NET Framework Library Source Code now available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx)

Comment: is it only for debugging? can I just browse .net source files in VS when no applications launched?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the microsoft .net libraries, if that's what you want,
see [Configuring Visual Studio To Debug Net Framework Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it is possible](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx). You can step through the BCL source code in Visual Studio when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at source files for an implementation of the Base Class Libraries, you can download look at the [source code of the mono project](http://mono-project.com/SVN).

This is different from the Microsoft implementation which is [also available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx).

I suggest you take a look at the licences of both and decide which one you would rather live with.